# maximum distance from origin to the curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the maximum distance from the origin to the curve

$$x^3 + y^3 - 3axy = 0$$

I've tried taking the partial derivatives with respect to x and y and dividing what I got.

$$\frac{df}{dx} = 3x^2 - 3ay$$
$$\frac{df}{dy} = 3y^2 - 3ax$$

$$\frac{x}{y} = (3x^2 - 3ay)/(3y^2 - 3ax)$$

$$(3x^2 - 3ay)y = (3y^2 - 3ax)x$$

I'm not sure if the $y$ and $x$ terms are related or how to proceed from here.

Comment: But, $x$ and $y$ can get indefinitely large, and so the distance to the origin...

Comment: I'm presuming you mean the distance from the origin to the loop that is formed?

Comment: I believe it is the origin of the loop that is formed.

Comment: It seems to me that the furthest point from the origin to the end of the loop would lie on the line y=x

Comment: would it be a valid assumption to say x=y?

Comment: I believe so, for all real values of a this surely works

Answer (score 1):

By considering $y = tx$, we get the parametric form of the curve as below

$$x = \frac{3at}{1 + t^3}$$

$$y = \frac{3at^2}{1 + t^3}$$

Then the distance from the origin is

$$L = \frac{3at\sqrt{1 + t^2}}{1 + t^3}$$

$$\frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{(1 - t)(1 + 3t^2 + t^3)}{(1 + t^3)^2\sqrt{1 + t^2}}$$

$$\frac{dL}{dt} = 0 \implies t = 1$$

$$x = y = \frac{3a}{2}$$

$$L = \frac{3a}{\sqrt{2}}$$

This is the local maximum distance from the origin.  This is derived without knowing how the curve looks like.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Equation is symmetric in $(x,y)$, so mirrors about line $(x=y)\tag1$

This is a typical Lagrange multiplier problem.

With the given constraint $ x^3 + y^3 - 3 a x y = F(x,y)$

Consider maximization of distance $x^2+y^2= G (x,y)$

Using partial differentiation for maximization

$$ \dfrac{F_x}{F_y}=\dfrac{G_x}{G_y} = \lambda $$

$$ \dfrac{3 x^2-3 a y }{3 y^2- 3 a x}=\dfrac{2x}{2y} $$

Simplify

$$x y +a (x+y)=0 $$

Can you take for solution further on with 1) and check  for any errors?

Answer (score -1):

Due to the fact the curve is symmetrical in y=x then the furthest point of the loop will also lie on this line, so solve this way!

Comment: That's not true: there could be two symmetric points $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ that are the furthest from the origin but outside the line $y=x$. Consider an ellipse with center $(0,0)$, minor axis along the line $y=x$ and major axis along $y=-x$. (In that case, the points on $y=x$ are the closest to the origin, but we could imagine symmetric curves where the points on that line aren't the closest and not the furthest from the origin).

Comment: But we're not talking about an ellipse we're talking about this specific equation - obviously there are curves where this isn't true but I presumed that the asker had at least drawn the general shape of this

Comment: if you sketch the curve to discover that the furthest point (of the loop) is on $y=x$, then you don't need calculus and the question don't make sense. If you don't have the curve at hand, you are using what you expect to be the answer in your reasoning, which is a logical problem.